# windows popup close before display dos . xls

Tags: javascript, excel, jsp, internet-explorer-8, response

I'm trying to display a document in a popup window on IE8 -- but before showing, the window closes automatically.

Here's the code:

javascript:

```
function hacerExportarExcel(){
   var url = contextPath + "/exportarCarteraCreditoExcel.do"
   window.setTimeout("window.open('"+url+"', '_blank', 'width=950,height=500,scrollbars=yes')",1000);

}
```

action:

```
try {

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=ConsultaCartera.xls");       
    consulta.setPdf(response.getOutputStream());
    administracionCreditoConsulta.exportarCarteraCreditoExcel(consulta); 

} catch (Exception e) {

    logger.logError(e);

} finally {

    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();

}
```

When asking for the new window it pop ups and starts loading, then it closes and gives me the following exception:

> 2012-06-27 11:01:01,951 ERROR [LoggingFilter] log() Exception (147):
>   ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:327)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:293)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:85)
>       at com.wincornixdorf.infinix.creditos.action.ExportarCarteraCreditoExcelAction.execute(ExportarCarteraCreditoExcelAction.java:82)

When I try doing this in IE 6 it does fine, the window pops up and the excel is shown. It's not working for IE 8 though...

anyone can help ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you can display this as inline content? My guess would be that IE8 is always going to attempt to download this file instead of displaying it in the window, which will make it automatically close the new window. Have you tried the same code with a different type of document just to make sure the rest of the logic is sound?

Comment: Hello!

Thanks for responding!

This happens only when I want to display a document type .xls, when a document type is .pdf works perfectly 

This is the code when the type is pdf 

try {
 response.setContentType("application/pdf");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; Grafico.pdf");
        consulta.setPdf(response.getOutputStream());

        administracionCreditoConsulta.exportarGrafico(consulta);
   
} catch (Exception e) {
 logger.logError(e);
} finally {
 response.getOutputStream().flush();
 response.getOutputStream().close();
}

The only difference is the ContentType

Comment: I would assume then that the browser does not know how to handle that document type in a window so it defaults to a download behavior; even though you have told it otherwise.

Comment: hello!

I was able to solve!

The change I made was to put in value the content type: "application/vnd.xls"

Thanks!

Comment: Nice find Edgar! Be sure to post that as the answer and accept it for future users.